# express app correct way to connect to mongo db?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following directory layout that contains a node.js / express application:

```
server.coffee
server.js
src
├── config
│   └── index.coffee
├── controllers
│   ├── index.coffee
│   └── user.coffee
├── index.coffee
├── models
│   └── user
│       └── user.coffee
├── routes.coffee
└── utils
    ├── dbconnect.coffee
views
├── 404.blade
├── 500.blade
├── index.blade
└── user
    ├── create.blade
```

the /src/config/index.coffee has details of the mongo URL which is i then export as DB_URL

```
#### Config file
# Sets application config parameters depending on `env` name

logger = require "../utils/logger"
logCategory = "Server config"

DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = "27017"
DB_NAME = "zmgc"
DB_URL = null
DB_USER = null
DB_PASS = null


# Connecting to dexies database on mongodb
boundServices = if process.env.VCAP_SERVICES then JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) else null
unless boundServices
    if DB_USER and DB_PASS
        DB_URL = "mongodb://#{DB_USER}:#{DB_PASS}@#{DB_HOST}:#{DB_PORT}/#{DB_NAME}"
    else
        DB_URL = "mongodb://#{DB_HOST}:#{DB_PORT}/#{DB_NAME}"
else
    service_type = "mongodb-1.8"
    credentials = boundServices["mongodb-1.8"][0]["credentials"]
    DB_URL = "mongodb://" + credentials["username"] + ":" + credentials["password"] + "@" + credentials["hostname"] + ":" + credentials["port"] + "/" + credentials["db"]

#Set the current environment to true in the env object
exports.setEnvironment = (env) ->
  logger.info "Set app environment: #{env}", logCategory

  switch(env)
    when "development"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = true
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = true
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = true
      exports.DB_URL = DB_URL

    when "testing"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = true
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = true
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = true
      exports.DB_URL = DB_URL

    when "staging"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = true
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = true
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = true
      exports.DB_URL = DB_URL

    when "production"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = false
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = false
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = false
      exports.DB_URL = DB_URL
    else
      logger.info "Environment #{env} not found", logCategory
```

and then in /src/utils/dbconnect.coffee, i have the following:

```
# Connecting to database on mongodb
config = require "../config/index"
logger = require("./logger")
mongoose = require("mongoose")
mongoose.set "debug", true

logCategory = "DATABASE Connection"

db_connect_mongo = init: (callback) ->
  self = this
  mongo_options = db:
      safe: true
  db_url = config.DB_URL
  mongoose.connect db_url, mongo_options
  db = self.db_mongo = mongoose.connection

  db.on "error", (error) ->
    logger.error "ERROR connecting to: " + db_url, logCategory
    callback error, null

  db.on "connected", ->
    logger.info "SUCCESSFULLY connected to: " + db_url, logCategory
    callback true, db

  db.on "disconnected", ->
    logger.info "DISCONNECTED from the database: " + db_url, logCategory

# check and connect to Redis

exports = module.exports = db_connect_mongo
```

am i correct in assuming that once i start the application, `/src/index.coffee` :

```
express = require "express"
logger = require "./utils/logger"

# Initialize logger
logger.configure()

#### Application initialization
# Create app instance.
app = express()

# Define Port
app.port = process.env.PORT or process.env.VMC_APP_PORT or process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT or 3000

# Config module exports has `setEnvironment` function that sets app settings depending on environment.
config = require "./config"

logCategory = "Server"

app.configure "development", "testing", "staging", "production", ->
  config.setEnvironment app.settings.env

# Database connection
dbconnection = require "./utils/dbconnect"
dbconnection.init (result) ->
  if result
    logger.info "Database initialized", logCategory
```

the connection stays open, so that i don't have to keep opening and closing this?

is this the correct approach to do this?

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you connect, the connection will stay open until explicitly disconnected or it goes idle for a while. From the docs:

> For long running applictions it is often prudent to enable keepAlive.
>   Without it, after some period of time you may start to see "connection
>   closed" errors for what seems like no reason. If so, after reading
>   this, you may decide to enable keepAlive:

Your `db_connect_mongo` violates the node convention that the first argument be `null` when invoking a callback in the success case. To correct this, don't use `callback(true, db)` to mean success, use `callback(null, db)`. Other than that and being a bit complicated for something that can and should be much simpler, what you have should work.

Comment: it does not work in my case, in that if i turn off mongo, and try to save something via the app, mongoose logs that there is a save being made, but that's it! i would like to be able to have a massage to say 'db not connected' ... how do i correct the node convention and how would you make this simpler? thanks

Comment: "How would you make this simpler" is a bit beyond the stackoverflow format, but just look at how much code you have like that giant switch statement that is 90% useless. Mongoose is probably queueing the commands while the DB is down which is part helpful and part annoying. It's unclear how to disable that if at all possible but maybe you can peak into the `mongoose.connection` object.

Comment: ok, but in regards to the `db_connect_mongo` violates, what do you mean?

Comment: See my edited answer. Instead of `callback(true, db)`, do `callback(null, db)`